# for loop using strip modifies file object?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand what the commented out lines of code below do. When the lines are commented out, the program works as expected: it reads the function tuple_to_word creates a dictionary with the lines of words.txt as the values.

When the code is uncommented out, however, the program only prints an empty dictionary. But I can't understand why the for loop would have any effect on the call to tuple_to_word. I am guessing that the for loop in question changes the underlying file object, but how?

```
fin = open('words.txt')
word_dict = {}
'''
for i in fin:
    word_dict[i.strip()] = 1
'''
def signature(s):
    t = list(s)
    t.sort()
    t = ''.join(t)
    return t    

def tuple_to_word():
    words_match_tuple = { }
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip().lower()
        t = signature(word)
        words_match_tuple.setdefault(t, []).append(word)

    return words_match_tuple

print tuple_to_word()
```

Comment: What is in the words.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: if you activate the code between ''' .. ''' this will parse the input file line by line. Then the function tuple_to_word() will find the file cursor at the end and there will be no line to parse from the input file.

You should either reopen the input file or go to the beginning of the file with:

```
fin.seek(0)
```